# Technology Themed Gift Basket

Tags: keyboard, mouse, media

For customer service week this year, I have the privileged task of creating a technology themed gift basket. I'm trying to keep the basket under $50 as I have a bluetooth keyboard/mouse combo that I'll be adding to it. Besides canned air and monitor wipes, are there any other recommendations for a PC based basket? I was thinking about a USB thumb drive and/or blank CD/DVD media. Any other ideas?

Comment: Although the question was closed for not being directly programming related, I thank all that responded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LED flashlights and multi-tools.
You can never have too many LED flashlights and multi-tools!

Answer (score 3):

There is a risk it might push you over your budget, but I would definitely check out www.thinkgeek.com.  They have a lot of very fun and off-the-wall gifts like caffeinated soap, fun t-shirts, pen drives, and the like.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for gifts for a Help Desk / Customer Service rep, then any of these would be nice.

- A remote electric shock device to buzz id10ts on the other end of the
  phone.
- A license to kill.
- A recording of David Spade doing the no commercial for when callers get
  put on hold.
- (for the guys) High Quality pictures of Natalie Portman, Robin Page (http://www.simple-talk.com/author/robyn-page/) or Sarah Chipps (http://girldeveloper.com/)

Comment: link for the Spade commercial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3NCxndXjsWg

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much want everything from http://www.thinkgeek.com